# show errors using html li tags using foreach loop in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, foreach

here's sample code...

```
string[] errors = new string[2];
if (txt_Username.Text.Trim() != null)
        {
            con.Open();
            int temp = 0;
           //fetch username from db

            if (temp != 0)
            {
                errors[0] = "username exists";
            }
        }
if (txt_email.Text.Trim() != null)
        {
            con.Open();
            int emailtemp = 0;

            //fetch email from db
            if (temp != 0)
            {
                errors[0] = "email exists";
            }
        }
if (errors == null || errors.Length == 0)
        {
//insert into db
}
   else{
lblES.Text = "<div class='error'>Errors<br /><hr ><ul></div>";
            foreach (string er in errors)
            {
                lblES.Text += "<li>" + er + "</li>";
            }
            lblES.Text += "</ul>";
}
```

None of the errors are shown!!! What's wrong with the code???

Sometimes only bullets are displayed without the error message!!!

Comment: Errors won't be null because you initialized it first thing in your code to an array that has a length of 2. This means the length will not be zero either.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of things that are wrong with your code:

You are storing both errors at location `0` in your array: `errors[0] = ...`. I would suggest using a list instead, and adding the errors as required:

```
var errors = new List<string>();     
// ..    
errors.Add("username exists");
```

This will let you test if errors were found properly:

```
if (errors.Any()) { ... }
```

Also, you are closing the `<div>` element before appending the `<li>`s and ending the `<ul>` element. Remove the closing div tag (`</div>`) from its current location, and append it at the very end.

Comment: i've also used an arraylist<> but still nothing is displayed!!!...              ArrayList errors = new ArrayList();    if(....){errors.Add("username exists");}    if(errors.Count > 1){ foreach (string er in errors)
                {
                   lblES.Text = lblES.Text + e;
                }